# Google Maps Overlay Infowindow Div

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a google map v3 with fusion table that I am looking to create a custom box with the content that would normally be displayed in an infowindow.

Much like http://www.instaearth.me or
http://chrismcaleenan.com/map/?page_id=7

So the user clicks on the marker and the content is loaded into a box/window/div that is not attached to the marker itself.

Does anyone know of any samples / tutorials where someone shows this being done.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Hey Erik, Ive done a lot of research on 'static infowindow position', and 'overlays'.  Nothing I can pull up gives me what I am looking for. As far as what I have tried .. I can get an overlay over a map but cannot load information from the fusion table on it(or to change on a mouse click). I have also used infobox, smartinfowindow and more but cannot get those to stay in a static position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FusionTablesLayer has a [FusionTablesMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent) which is returned on a click (if you add a click event listener to the FusionTablesLayer).  That Object contains the data in the row associated with that geographic object (icon, polyline or polygon), and you can use it to populate an HTML div on your page.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries.html), zoom in past zoom level 2 to see the FusionTable code work, at zoom 0, 1 it uses the KmlLayer

Comment: This should get me going in the right direction. Thanks for the help.